# nlog4.x ${longdate} works on Npgsql 2.2.7 but does not work on Npgsql 3.x

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, nlog

I am using NLog4.1 version for logging.

My "NLog.config" looks like:

```xml
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
    <connectionStringName>PRODUCTION</connectionStringName>
    <commandText>
        INSERT INTO "MY"."LOG_TABLE" ( "ENTRY_DATE" ) VALUES ( @ENTRY_DATE );
    </commandText>

    <parameter name="@entry_date" layout="${longdate}"/>
</target>
```

Logging is OK when I use Npgsql v2.2.7 Nuget package.

But when upgrade Nuget package to [Npgsql v3.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/3.2.2) and EntityFramework6.Npgsql to v3.1.1 logging gives error on:

```cs
protected static NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
Logger.Info("Logger started.");
```

The following error:

> 42804: column "ENTRY_DATE" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Npgsql.PostgresException: 42804: column "ENTRY_DATE" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text
>
> [PostgresException (0x80004005): 42804: column "ENTRY_DATE" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text]

web config changes

for v2.2.7:

```xml
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

for v3.2.2:

```xml
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Postgresql DB Column definition :

```
 "ENTRY_DATE" timestamp without time zone
```

What changes when upgrade to v3.x? Please help to use for right way on v3.x.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tablo column definition :  "ENTRY_DATE" timestamp without time zone

Comment: FYI, all database parameters from the NLog database target are of type text. Maybe you need a parse in the query.

Comment: @Julian thanks for reply. Probably i need to write my custom logger classes considering "NLog database target are of type text". But i am wondering if there is a way no code changes need when migrate to Npgsql new 3.x version while Nlog 4.x working with Npgsql 2.2.7 correctly.

Comment: Customer logger classs is not needed. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated answer

Since NLog 4.6 it's possible to configure the parameter type with the dbType attribute. NLog 4.6 has been released in March 2019.

E.g.

```
<parameter name="@entry_date" layout="${longdate}" dbType="DateTime" />
```

See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target

> dbType - One of the values of DbType (e.g. "Int32", "Decimal", "DateTime"), or a value of DBType like prefixed with the property name, e.g. "SqlDbType.NChar" will set the property "SqlDbType" on "NChar". Another example: "NpgsqlDbType.Json" with NpgsqlParameter. Introduced in NLog 4.6. Since NLog 4.7 not case-sensitive any more

#### Original answer:

The parameters from the database target in NLog are text parameters.

It seems that  Npgsql/PostgreSQL/EntityFramework6 is now more picky.

You need to convert the `string` to the `timestamp` type. You can do that in the query with the `to_timestamp` PostgreSQL function:

```sql
 <commandText>
    INSERT INTO "MY"."LOG_TABLE" ( "ENTRY_DATE" ) 
    VALUES (to_timestamp(@ENTRY_DATE,  'YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS.MS');
 </commandText>
```

The format in C#: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff`, in PostgreSQL: `YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS.MS` - see [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Thanks @Julian. conversion function works on SQL statement.